# MYSQL: product - attribute relations

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out relations between products and product attributes.
I have a `product` table and a `product_attributes` table.
Product can have multiple attributes.
I need a query for finding all products which have ONE specific attribute AND one of another ones.
E.g. product with attribute_value_id "1" AND this product must also have attribute_value_id IN (2, 3, 4)

I thought this would do it, but it does not:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id 
FROM `product` p 
JOIN `product_attribute` pa ON (p.product_id = pa.product_id) 
WHERE pa.attribute_value_id = 1 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(2, 3, 4)
```

### product

product_id

### product_attribute

product_id | attribute_id | attribute_value_id

attribute_id is attribute group (e.g. color, gender)
attribute_value_id is specific value (e.g. blue, men, women)

In another words I need all prodcuts for men which are blue or red.

Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `WHERE pa.attribute_value_id = 1 AND pa.attribute_value_id IN(2, 3, 4)` - that of course can’t work, because pa.attribute_value_id will not have the value 1 _and_ one of 2, 3 or 4 _at the same time_, technically impossible (unless you already got yourself one of dem nice quantum computer thingies.) The usual solution to getting records that have a certain (or minimum) number of specified attributes works by GROUPing, COUNTing and then using HAVING to check what number of records the group contains. (To demand that 1 be among them might need some additional check.)

Comment: OR, not AND, and then GROUP BY... HAVING COUNT (...) >= 2 - or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late here, but I guess late is better than never :p

The `subquery` select records where either `condition 1` or `condition 2` matches. If a product matches both conditions, 2 rows will appear in the result.

The `outer query` do a `count()` on the result & check for `count = 2`, which output distinct `product` where 2 conditions are matched.

```
-- outer query
SELECT
    a.product_id, count(a.attribute_value_id) as attribute_count
FROM

-- subquery
(
    SELECT p.*, pa.attribute_value_id
    FROM
        product p
        JOIN product_attribute pa 
            ON (p.product_id = pa.product_id) 
    WHERE
        -- condition 1
        pa.attribute_value_id = 1 
        -- condition 2
        OR pa.attribute_value_id IN(2, 3, 4)
) a

GROUP BY a.product_id
HAVING attribute_count = 2;
```